Flutter Java and Gradle version compatibility issue
I'm trying to create a Flutter app, but I'm getting a message about a version conflict between Java and Gradle. The output I received says
The configured version of Java detected may conflict with the Gradle version in your new Flutter app.

[RECOMMENDED] If so, to keep the default Gradle version 8.3, make sure to download a compatible Java version
(Java 17 <= compatible Java version < Java 21).
You may configure this compatible Java version by running:
flutter config --jdk-dir=<JDK_DIRECTORY>
...
Alternatively, to continue using your configured Java version, update the Gradle version specified in the following file to a compatible Gradle version
(compatible Gradle version range: 8.4 - 8.7):

I am not sure how to fix this. Should I change the Java version or update Gradle? What is the best way to solve this issue to make my Flutter app run without errors?

Just providing the required Java version is usually the easier way.

this is really harassing. solved this by changing kotlin, gradle & wrapper version again n again. try this  1)ext.kotlin_version = '2.0.10' 2)classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.3.0' 3)distributionUrl=https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.5-all.zip

As a message says, you basically have 2 options. Both are fine, I guess, but preferred way is mostly depends on how you would like to manage your dev environment.

Set JDK for Flutter explicitly with flutter config --jdk-dir=<JDK_DIRECTORY>

Pros:
– Explicit dependencies is usually better, cause you won't have sudden update which brakes everything.
– Do not depends on Android Studio (this is where your current JDK is from, I guess) – you can even delete it if you want and can manage your android development independently.
Cons:
– Manually watching for JDK updates, guessing which vendor, patch release you want (OpenJDK latest patch is usually given though :) ).
So, for this method to work, you would have to install JDK separately and then provide it's path to Flutter.

Update Gradle.

Pros:
– Usually harmless and you'd want to do it anyways cause newer versions is usually more performant and still maintains backward compatibility (inside major version at least)
Cons:
– You might need to update other android-related dependencies as well (such as Android Gradle Plugin, Kotlin plugin etc) for them to be compatible with JDK 21. Might be frustrating and even undoable if you're not very deep into android development.
If you choose this path, you should modify version manually in gradle-wrapper.properties here: <you_project_path>/android/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties.
You'll see something like this there:
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-8.3-all.zip

Just change 8.3 there in last line to, lets say, 8.7 and you're good to go.

For me you need to upgrade your gradle it's better than downgrade JAVA.
But for many people it's different. If you think u will upgrade flutter, upgrade gradle is a good solution (upgrade flutter it's good for more compatibility and performance on smartphone). But if you do, you will probably need to update part of your library.
If you don't want to upgrade Flutter, I think you can downgrade JAVA.
I hope my answer will help you or other people

When looking for a "reputable source", see the Compatibility Matrix.
However, there is also one for Android Gradle Plugin and for Android Studio.
Android SDK currently builds with JDK 17, which usually can be found there (when downloaded):
flutter config --jdk-dir=%USERPROFILE%\.jdks\corretto-17.0.13

When Flutter demands: Gradle 8.7, this would be the same as Android Studio Ladybug | 2024.2.1
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-8.7-bin.zip
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists

There's also a command to update that:
cd android
gradlew.bat wrapper --gradle-version=8.7


But this permits at most AGP 8.6.0, because  AGP 8.7.2 requires a later Gradle version.
This also means Android build-tools 34.0.0, which seemingly support API level 35:

The maximum API level that Android Gradle plugin 8.6 supports is API level 35.


I encountered the same issue when using the latest version of Android Studio, which came with a newer version of Java. Switching Flutter to the master channel resolved the problem for me.
